# Can I store multiple configs on a Cisco device?

Tags: cisco, configuration

Since we are a small shop without the means to have a test environment, I often find myself using the live equipment after hours for testing. I'm always backing up configs to the tftp, testing a different config, and then just restoring the old config. Is there any reason I can't do a "copy running-config backup-config," then work on my test config, the do a "copy run test-config" and then do a "copy backup-config run" when I'm done for the night? Then I could have my test config all ready to go for the next round without mucking around with the tftp.

Just a thought. Anyone got any arguments against it? Does it even work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no temp storage, though, if your router supports it, you can copy configurations to an archive, see: [Config Archive](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t7/feature/guide/gtrollbk.html)

Another option available is to use the startup-config as your 'known-good'. Once you've got a a solid config, copy it to startup-config. Make changes to running-config for tests. In the event you really screw up, you can always reboot to a known good config.

Comment: Yeah, definitely try not to touch startup until I'm sure things are running well.